# ggplot2 cannot find function "ggtitle"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I'm using ggtree, which uses ggplot2, to plot a phylogeny.

I'm using R version 4.3.1, with ggplot version 3.4.2, and ggtree 3.8.2.

the script (executed from a temp file) that gives the issue is very simple:

```
library(ggtree)
tree <- read.tree('fa/clustal.DEG20010516.input.newick')
svg('fa/phylo.svg')
ggtree(tree) + theme_tree2() + geom_tiplab(align=TRUE, linesize=0.5) +xlim(0,0.6) + ggtitle('DEG')
dev.off()
```

but this returns an error:

```
! The tree contained negative edge length. If you want to ignore the edge, you
can set `options(ignore.negative.edge=TRUE)`, then re-run ggtree.
Error in ggtitle("DEG") : could not find function "ggtitle"
```

I'm getting instructions from https://4va.github.io/biodatasci/r-ggtree.html

how can I set the title when the standard way doesn't work?

Comment: In the example on the linked page, they load `tidyverse` before `ggtree`. Does running `library(tidyverse)` or just `library(ggplot2)` resolve the error?

Comment: ...or `+ ggplot2::ggtitle('DEG')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Seth and @Jon Spring said in the comments, you can't use the `ggtitle()` function unless you load the ggplot2 package. I can reproduce the problem using a newick alignment file from a previous project:

```r
library(ggtree)

tree <- read.tree('~/Desktop/gisaid_mafft_tree.txt')
svg('phylo.svg')
ggtree(tree) + theme_tree2() + geom_tiplab(align=TRUE, linesize=0.5) +xlim(0,0.6) + ggtitle('DEG')
#> Error in ggtitle("DEG"): could not find function "ggtitle"
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

Loading the ggplot2 library first solves the problem:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtree)

tree <- read.tree('~/Desktop/gisaid_mafft_tree.txt')
svg('phylo.svg')
ggtree(tree) + theme_tree2() + geom_tiplab(align=TRUE, linesize=0.5) +xlim(0,0.6) + ggtitle('DEG')
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>